# Galois group to Sextic Polynomial with Two Real Roots

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots

I have the following polynomial 
$$f(x,Q)=0.064x^6+0.96x^4+4.8x^2-(13.824Q)x+8=0$$
where the variable $Q$ is in the range $]1,2\pi]$. This polynomial is obtained from an equation that describes a nozzle. From the theory I know there are certainly two positive real roots: I have done the check for different values of $Q$ and Wolfram confirms it.

I need the formula to get the two real positive solutions by only changing the value of $Q$: then I have to implement this formula in MATLAB. For what I have written above I think the sextic has a solvable Galois group so can be exactly expressed in terms of radicals.

I am an aerospace engineer and to be honest I don't know where to start with Galois theory.

Comment: Why do you think it has a solvable Galois group? I'm not saying it doesn't, but I myself don't see why it would.

Comment: I computed it for $Q=2$ and it isn't solvable. That means you're out of luck for general $Q$.

Comment: I think there is a solvable Galois group because this equation is obtained from a physical phenomena that is the number of Mach inside a nozzle. We have that $Q$ is an adimensioanl area (this area varies inside a nozzle) while $x$ is the number of Mach. From the theory we surely know that, for a given $Q$, there are two positive real values of $x$: the first one is of the type $0<x<1$ while the second is $x>1$. So I need the formula to get the two real positive solutions by only changing the value of $Q$ but unfortunately I don't know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Being a physical phenomenon, it's even less likely to have an exact solution. Most polynomials don't have solvable Galois group, and physical problems tend not to have exact solutions. I don't know MATLAB, but I'm under the impression it's pretty good at finding the roots approximately. If that's not good enough, there are exact formulas for sixth degree equations, but they involve transcendental functions.

Comment: MATLAB can find both solutions but in my case the "problem" is that I have to do this operation for more than $3000$ values of $Q$ and it requires a great amount of time. The fact is that I have to do other operations after these calculations and so I was wondering if there was an exact formula to accelerate the process.
Just a curiosity: is it so hard to find the roots, if you have a solvable Galois group, for a sextic polynomial? By the way thank you for your answers, I appreciate that.

Comment: Well the Galois group for this isn't solvable, like I said. But regardless there is an exact formula involving transcendental functions that may be suitable for your purposes. I wasn't able to find it with a quick Google search though. I know that in C++ finding the roots approximately would take a trivial amount of time, probably much faster than MATLAB. In the code we use at work we find roots of functions that are much slower to compute than polynomials using the bisection method very quickly in C++.